# using a div class doesnt render html page

Tags: javascript, json

```js
let x=[];
const json1 = '{"https://www.w3schools.com":"w3schools"}';
const obj1 = JSON.parse(json1);
ol = document.createElement('ol');
ser.appendChild(ol);
for (var key in obj1){
x= document.createElement('li');
x.innerHTML="<a href=" + key + ">" + obj1[key]+"</a>";
ol.appendChild(x);
}
```

```css
.ser{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ser">welcome</div>
```

I have used a div class called 'ser' and I get a console error as 'ser is not defined'
Note: but if I change to a div id and change the css value from .ser to #ser html page renders ok.
So I wish where I am conceptually going wrong in using the div class syntax.Please advise.

Comment: Due to an IE quirk, adding an `id` to an element makes it exist for your JS code to reference directly. This was kept for legacy reasons but in theory you would have to declare the variable first, using for instance `const ser = document.getElementById('ser');`. This doesn't work with classes because the whole point of classes is to apply them to multiple elements.

Comment: The correct way forward is to a) not use w3schools (the most important advice here) and b) decide whether this is a unique element and use an id or whether a class is more suitable, then use document.getElementById() or document.querySelector(). I recommend the latter since the argument is the exact same as the selector in your CSS.

Comment: Chris :) w3schools is just a variable I set, I se MDN docs most of the time

Comment: tried and it worked both ways : 
document.getElementById('ser').appendChild(ol); document.querySelector('.ser').appendChild(ol);

Comment: Yes, a 3rd variant is `document.querySelector('#ser')`

Comment: this worked too; so got conceptually your 3rd variant meaning ...( and as per MDN we can use the query selector to query by ID also, which by the way I never implemented before )..details: 
<style>#ser{color: cyan;}</style>
<body>
<div id="ser">welcome</div>
<script>
let x=[];
const json1 = '{"https://www.google.com":"google"}';
const obj1 = JSON.parse(json1);
ol = document.createElement('ol');
document.querySelector('#ser').appendChild(ol);
for (var key in obj1){
x= document.createElement('li');
x.innerHTML="<a href=" + key + ">" + obj1[key]+"</a>";
ol.appendChild(x);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define *ser* by classname:

```
var ser = document.querySelector('.ser')
```

or by id, since querySelector returns first match

```
var ser = document.getElementById('ser')
```

Comment: by using the queryselector approach document.querySelector('.ser').appendChild(ol);